# Git doesn't create .gitconfig when it's inside a function

Tags: bash, git, shell, git-config

I'm a fairly new user in Bash and Git in general and I'm scratching my head about what the problem could be. I'm creating a code that checks if .gitconfig exists and if it doesn't it allows you to configure it almost automatically using a read command to get your email and username and apply them in a line of code.

Code example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# colors
RED='\033[0;31m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
YELLOW='\033[1;33m'
NO_COLOR='\033[0m'

# function git
git () { 
   printf "${RED}Set your Git email\n${NO_COLOR}"
   read GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL
   git config --global user.email "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"
   printf "${RED}Set your Git username\n${NO_COLOR}"
   read GIT_AUTHOR_USERNAME
   git config --global user.name "$GIT_AUTHOR_USERNAME"
   git config --list | grep user.email && git config --list | grep user.name
}

# git check & configuration
if [ -f ".gitconfig" ]; then
   printf "${YELLOW}Git was previously configured\n${NO_COLOR}"
   exit
else
   git
   printf "${YELLOW}Done\n${NO_COLOR}"
   exit
fi
```

If it doesn't exist, it calls a function to configure it but after some quick debugging using the `set -x` command I figured out the file .gitconfig is not created at all but it does when I do it myself outside a function. All it does is go back to `read GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL`, apply the code `git config --global user.email "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"` and go back to the first read command. I want the code to check for .gitconfig and if it exists it'll also ask if the user wants to re-configure their Git details. I'm super close on doing so.

Is there any way I can fix it or do it another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've defined the function `git`, any invocation of the name `git` in that shell process will refer to that shell function.  If you'd like to invoke the program `git`, then you need to prefix it with the built-in `command`:

```
command git config --global user.name "$GIT_AUTHOR_USERNAME"
```

If it wasn't your intention to override the `git` command, then you probably want to name your shell function differently, which avoids the problem altogether.

Comment: Naming the function something else seems like the much better solution.

Comment: Apparently simply renaming the shell function seems to fix the issue. Thank you for pointing this out!